# how to delete specific nodes and their children based on attributes in the parent node?

Tags: c#, xml

first, sorry for my bad english, i'm learning yet. So, I have to delete specifics nodes of a xml file according with their attributes. This is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Lista>
  <Indice value="8">
    <Palavra value="casa" />
    <Significados>s1,,,,</Significados>
  </Indice>
  <Indice value="49">
    <Palavra value="teste" />
    <Significados>1,2,,,</Significados>
  </Indice>
  <Indice value="72">
    <Palavra value="cristiano" />
    <Significados>ornelas,ribeiro,,,</Significados>
  </Indice>
  <Indice value="72">
    <Palavra value="teste2" />
    <Significados>s2,s3,,,</Significados>
  </Indice>
</Lista>
```

I have to delete all Indice nodes and your childrens that have the attribute value="72" for example. How can I do that? The language is c# and the xml file after of delete must stay in this form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Lista>
  <Indice value="8">
    <Palavra value="casa" />
    <Significados>s1,,,,</Significados>
  </Indice>
  <Indice value="49">
    <Palavra value="teste" />
    <Significados>1,2,,,</Significados>
  </Indice>     
</Lista>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
XDocument xdoc=XDocument.Parse(xmlStr); //or XDocument.Load

var matchingElements = xdoc.Root
                        .Descendants("Indice")
                        .Where(e => (int)e.Attribute("value") == 72)
                        .ToList();
foreach(var elem in matchingElements)
{
    elem.Remove();
}

xdoc.Save(newFileName);
```

saves the following doc:

```
<Lista>
  <Indice value="8">
    <Palavra value="casa" />
    <Significados>s1,,,,</Significados>
  </Indice>
  <Indice value="49">
    <Palavra value="teste" />
    <Significados>1,2,,,</Significados>
  </Indice>
</Lista>
```

Comment: Can use `matchingElements.Remove()` instead of the `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative to Spender although he should get the question answered if his works.

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("xml path");
        XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Lista");
        foreach (XmlNode nodes in node.SelectNodes("Indice/@value"))
        {

            if (nodes.Value == "72")
            {
                nodes.RemoveAll();
            }
        }
```